# Language Fallback doesn't work for glass Sitecore query

Tags: sitecore, glass-mapper, sitecore8.2

I am using sitecore 8.2 and glassmapper 4.3.

I am able to get fallback item using `Isitecorecontext.GetItem<T>(path)` but when I tried to read item using sitecore query like below

```
  public partial interface T
{
    [SitecoreQuery("./*[@@templatename='TemplateName']", InferType =true, IsLazy = true, IsRelative = true)]
    IMultiSiteContext ConfigurationRoot { get; set; }

}
```

ConfigurationRoot is extra property created in partial interface of that T